# Can I send scripted commands to a grunt shell from a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, apache-pig

I'm using `apache-pig` for a project I'm working on. I have a script that moves some files around and then starts pig. Once pig starts it brings up a grunt shell. I was wondering if it is possible for the script to give the grunt shell commands like executing a pig script (`exec customer.pig`). Is this possible or do I just have to break it up into separate scripts?

Comment: Will the grunt shell read commands from standard input? If yes, just do `apache-pig < grunt.commands.file`

Comment: What do you mean by commands from standard input?

Comment: I assumed your grunt shell is an interactive shell, and you want to send a pre-defined series of commands to it. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah and I think I figured out what you meant and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to glenn from the comments above. I just had to make a file, I called it `commands` and then when I run pig I just use `pig < commands`.